# Can't get Debug, Verbose log on Nougat

Tags: android, android-studio, sony

My Device: Sony Xperia XA1 Nougat(7.0)

I want to show a log on Android Monitor like this:

```
public static final String  TAG   = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final boolean DEBUG = true;

if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onResume()");
```

But..when I open the monitor window, I can't see this log even the log level is Verbose/Debug. I only can see I/W/E level on Android Monitor, and it always show:

```
I/art: Enter while loop...
```

Is it a security issue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just replace `DEBUG` with `BuildConfig.DEBUG`

Comment: Is the device rooted? From Android 4.1 onwards ANY logcat app needs root access in order to show logs properly. As per this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=scd.lcex&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dlog+cat+extreme+play+store&pcampaignid=APPU_1_TSpQWdPED8TSgAaUg4SQCw

Comment: I have the same issue. This is new on Sony XA series with Android 7. There isn't seem to be any way to enable Debug logs so far

Comment: Same here using a Sony XA1 @nLL

Comment: I added `^(?!(Enter while loop.))` to Logcat > Edit Configurations > Logcat Message to avoid seeing it while we wait for a solution. This seems to be a flag left by a developer.

Comment: Please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351870/logcat-messages-not-shown-with-xperia-xa1-ultra

Comment: You can refer this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351870/logcat-messages-not-shown-with-xperia-xa1-ultra