# Logcat messages not shown with Xperia XA1 ultra

Tags: android-logcat, android-studio-3.0, sony-xperia

Hi when I debug my apps with Sony Xperia XA1 Ultra in android studio, debug and verbose logs do not appear. My phone is running Android 8.0. I have installed the necessary driver and have tested with another phone (Sony Xperia Z1 Compact) and it outputs the logcat messages. Anybody else with the same issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logcat not showing debug level messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063164/logcat-not-showing-debug-level-messages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log.d messages are ignored in some models. You can **use Log.i** to solve the problem. To replace in all of your project files, you can follow:
[Find and replace Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249274/find-and-replace-android-studio)

Comment: Where did you find out that? Seems like that is happening with my device too.